# How to perform XML Element substitution in config.wxi using Replace Tokens?

Tags: xml, azure-devops, wix, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

I am building an Azure Devops Release pipeline and I have a WIX config file in my source code with the following structure

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Include>
  <?define Key ="MyValue"?>
</Include>
```

I would like to replace "MyValue" with "MyNewValue" using the Replace Tokens package
[(link here)](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=qetza.replacetokens)

Following the answer given [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67729738/how-to-perform-xml-element-substitution-in-web-config-using-replace-tokens#comment119782602_67767277).

I have `<Include>` as my token prefix and `</Include>` as my token suffix. I've added the following pipeline variable:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TXMgd.png)
When I build my pipeline it finds the file correctly, but doesn't find any variables to replace, am I missing something to link the variables step to the pipeline variables?

alternatively I was thinking the '<?' tags could be throwing it off or perhaps it's just not compatible with the WIX xml files?

Comment: You can use a powershell script to modify the config xml file.  It would be very similar to my answer at following : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76365529/how-to-invoke-powershell-script-from-command-prompt-that-updates-xml-file/76366873#76366873

Comment: I have opted for a powershell script in the end thanks!

Comment: Do you need any support?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not just pass the preprocessor variable via the .wixproj or command-line (whichever way you are building). That way you avoid the include file completely and have a much simpler solution.

I cover this technique in [Episode 12 of the Deployment Dojo - All the Ways to Change. Variables and Variables. Directories and Properties:](https://www.youtube.com/live/g1PBKhq2oe8)

```xml
<Project Sdk="WixToolset.Sdk/4.0.0">
  <PropertyGroup>
   <DefineConstants>Key=MyValue</DefineConstants>
  </PropertyGroup>
</Project>
```

Then you can easily override the value with `msbuild -p:Key=MyNewValue`.

Comment: Thanks for this that looks really cool, do you know by any chance if the inner '<?' tags (instead of '<') might throw things off here? Will check out the episode though thanks!

Comment: The `<?` indicates a preprocessing instruction. In the WiX Toolset, that is evaluated before the build (by the preprocessor). I don't really follow your question after that.